# How to emplace elements while constructing std::vector?

Tags: c++11, vector, constructor, emplace

I want to construct an `std::vector` with some elements having these elements constructed by some particular constructor rather than the default constructor. In other words I want to emplace the elements while constructing the vector. How can I do that?

Consider [this](https://godbolt.org/g/sWNxJv):

```
struct Item
{
    Item(double) {}
    Item(const Item&) = delete;
    Item(Item&&) = delete;
};
std::vector<Item> vv(10, 3.14); // Fails! Tries to copy while I want to emplace.
```

Comment: Perhaps a vector is the wrong container for you, perhaps you should use a [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead? Or perhaps you could elaborate about the *actual* problem you have? *Why* you came up with solution you want help with? This is a very typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) type of question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Actually, not `std::vector` nor `std::array` but the built-in dynamic array is the data structure that fits best to the purpose (dynamic but fixed size, no modifications). But the built-in dynamic arrays don't support this *emplace-while-constructing* functionality.

Comment: Well considering that "dynamic arrays" (I assume you mean [*variable-length arrays*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)?) doesn't exist in standard C++ that's not a choice either. Or do you mean `new[]`? And perhaps the *original problem* you have could be solved some other way?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I meant `new[]`. The *original problem* is to have a collection of predefined (but known at runtime, not compile-time) amount of `std::thread`s that are initialized with the same lambda. Thus copy is forbidden and it would be nice to avoid move as well (as ideally I shouldn't have to move).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the vector constructor that takes two iterators. For example you could use iterators from a `vector<double>`.

```
std::vector<double> init(10, 3.14);
std::vector<Item> vv(init.begin(), init.end());
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yTgoR2R9SXei1Oy6).

Or you could write your own custom iterator class to do the initialization:

```
struct ItemInitializer {
  int index;
  double value;

  using value_type = double;
  using difference_type = int;  
  using pointer = const double*;
  using reference = const double&;
  using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

  ItemInitializer() : index(0), value(0.0) {}
  ItemInitializer(int index, double v = 0.0) : index(index), value(v) {}

  bool             operator!=(const ItemInitializer& other) const { return other.index != index; }
  ItemInitializer& operator++() { index++; return *this; }
  ItemInitializer  operator++(int) { ItemInitializer ret(index, value); index++; return ret; }
  const double&    operator*() const { return value; }  
  const double*    operator->() const { return &value; } 
};

std::vector<Item> vv(ItemInitializer{0, 3.14}, ItemInitializer{10});
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Uk8jrlL1PXA8YriK).

Comment: The first code block is good. But what's the point of the second? I couldn't see much difference between it and ```std::vector<Item> vv; vv.assign(10, Item{3.14});```

Comment: @atakli `std::vector<Item> vv; vv.assign(10, Item{3.14});` will not compile if `Item` is not copyable or movable. The first code block involves allocating a temporary `vector<double>` so perhaps in some performance critical code the second code block would be an optimization.

Answer (score 5):

Your `Item` class doesn't support copies nor moves. This will prevent most operations on `std::vector` from compiling, including `std::vector::reserve` and `std::vector::resize`. If you really have such a class, you might want an `std::vector<std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(Item), alignof(Item)>>` instead.

If you can add a move constructor to `Item`, you can create your helper function instead *(as the constructor overload that you're using is defined in terms of copying)*. Note that the version below only works for unary constructors.

```
template <typename T, typename Arg>
auto make_vector(std::size_t n, Arg&& arg)
{
    std::vector<T> result;
    result.reserve(n);

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        result.emplace_back(arg);

    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
auto vec = make_vector<Item>(10, 3.14);
```

Comment: Nononon the fold expression with a comma was great, put it back! It's not even in the edit history :/

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: it was doing the wrong thing :P

Comment: Oh well. It made me realize that a comma is actually an operator :D

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I don't need that operations on `std::vector` to compile (as mentioned in the comment to the question). In fact I need only constructor (the one I want) and the destructor. Your suggestion is actually the workaround that I have in the code for now։) The drawback is: *defauct constructor + reserve (that can cause reallocation)* instead of *the constructor I want*. The workaround would have no drawback (except of more lines of code) if there were a constructor of `std::vector` that just reserves.

Comment: Answer by chris drew is correct in my opinion. Vector allows constructing from the iterators and it emplaces the element.