# Emplacement-like construction for std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, emplace

Imagine I want to construct a fixed-size `std::vector` of objects without move or copy constructors, such as `std::atomic<int>`. In this case the underlying `std::atomic` class has a 1-arg constructor which takes an `int`, as well as a default constructor (which initializes the value to 0).

Using the `initializer_list` syntax like `std::vector<std::atomic<int>> v{1,2,3}` doesn't work, because the arguments are first converted to the element type `T` of the vector as part of the creation of the `initializer_list` and so the copy or move constructor will be invoked.

In the particular case of `std::atomic<int>` I can default-construct the vector and then mutate the elements after:

```
std::vector<std::atomic<int>> v(3);
v[0] = 1;
v[1] = 2;
v[2] = 3;
```

However, in addition to being ugly and inefficient, it isn't a general solution since many objects may not offer post-construction mutation equivalent to what you could get by calling the appropriate constructor.

Is there any way to get the "emplace-like" behavior that I want at vector construction?

Comment: Seriously, I would just use `std::deque`. But if you can't, the only way to do what you want is through a custom allocator.

Comment: @Brian - does `std::deque` allow this construction idiom?

Comment: With `std::deque` you'll have to emplace the elements one by one, but it'll work because adding elements to the beginning or end doesn't move any of the other elements.

Comment: @Brian - right, it's at least better in `std::vector` in that respect, unfortunately sometimes I need the guarantee of contiguous storage that `vector` offers. I am also interested in the custom allocator approach: it isn't obvious to me how a custom allocator gets around the `vector` constructor interface.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to emplace elements while constructing std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46686258/how-to-emplace-elements-while-constructing-stdvector)

Comment: It seems to me this is the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193484/how-to-declare-a-vector-of-atomic-in-c , with the words shuffled around a bit

Comment: @M.M - it's a fair bit different. The OP there wanted to `push_back` elements into a vector, which isn't ever going to be allowed for non-movable types since there is a potential resizing which requires moveability. The idea of emplacing objects directly into a newly constructed vector, however, can work in theory and in practice, as the last part of the answer below shows using the constructor that takes two iterators.

Answer (score 2):

A general solution is to make your vector take a custom allocator whose `construct` method performs the appropriate initialization. In the code below, `v` uses the `MyAllocator<NonMovable>` allocator rather than `std::allocator<NonMovable>`. When the `construct` method is called with no arguments, it actually calls the constructor with the appropriate argument. In this way, the default constructor can initialize the elements properly.

(For simplicitly, I have made `next_value` static in this example, but it could just as well be a non-static member variable that's initialized when `MyAllocator` is constructed.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>
#include <new>
#include <vector>

struct NonMovable {
    NonMovable(int x) : x(x) {}
    const int x;
};

template <class T>
struct MyAllocator {
    typedef T value_type;
    static int next_value;
    T* allocate(size_t n) {
        return static_cast<T*>(::operator new(n * sizeof(T)));
    }
    void deallocate(T* p, size_t n) {
        ::operator delete(p);
    }
    template <class U>
    void construct(U* p) {
        new (p) U(++next_value);
    }
};

template <class T> int MyAllocator<T>::next_value = 0;

int main() {
    std::vector<NonMovable, MyAllocator<NonMovable>> v(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", v[i].x);
    }
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a89fddd325514bf

This is the only possible solution when you're not allowed to touch the `NonMovable` class and its constructor may require multiple arguments. In the case where you only need to pass one argument to each constructor, there is a much simpler solution that uses the range constructor of `std::vector`, like so:

```
std::vector<int> ints(10);
std::iota(ints.begin(), ints.end(), 1);
std::vector<NonMovable> v(ints.begin(), ints.end());
```

(Though if you can't afford the extra memory, then you'll have to write a custom iterator, which will be a lot more code.)